# In how many ways can the passengers be conveyed to the neighboring village from the train station?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> 25 passengers arrive at a railway station and proceed to the neighboring village. At the station there are 2 coaches accommodating 4 each & 3 carts accommodating 3 each. Find the number of ways in which they can proceed to the village assuming that the conveyances are always fully occupied & that the conveyances are all distinguishable from each other.

My solution was that select any 17 passengers out of 25 passengers, then we can group these 17 passengers into 2 groups containing 4 persons each and 3 groups containing 3 persons each respectively.
After doing we get $$\frac{25!}{8!(3!)^3(4!)^2}$$
Now the remaining 8 passengers will be seated in carts containing 4 persons each so it would be $$\frac{8!}{4!4!}$$ So final answer is
$$\frac{25!}{(4!)^4(3!)^3}$$
But the answer given is $$\frac{25!}{(4!)^4(3!)^34}$$
Can anyone tell how here in denominator 4 is coming and my mistake?

Comment: so you are assuming that the 8 leftover passenger would take a second train with the same cart composition for further travel (or the first train travels back to pick up the leftovers) - while this may certainly be a possibility, it is unclear to me that this is what the problem is asking

Comment: According to your interpretation, the two coaches must each be used twice.  Does the order in which the two coaches are used matter?

Comment: Are you assuming that, given sufficient passengers, any available vehicle must be used?  Without something like that...we  could, say, use cart $1$ seven times and then coach $1$ for the last $4$ people.  And so on.

Comment: @pygri the 2 carts which have accomodates 4 passengers has to come back  to take the remaining 8 passengers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have posed can best be understood using the concept of *labeled* and *unlabeled* groups or teams

Here the groups are labeled by the *distinct* vehicles used.

Had **four** coaches and three carts been present at the station. the number of groups would have been $\Large\frac{25!}{(4!)^4(3!)^3}$, or in longer form commonly used for forming teams, $\binom{25}{4}\binom{21}4\binom{17}4\binom{13}4\binom93\binom63\binom33$

But only **two** coaches are available, and  commonsense  would dictate that using these two coaches a second time would be the best way to transport the entire lot, so they would be transported, (with $\;\mathcal{C}$ for coaches and $c$ for carts), say, as $\;\mathcal{C_1,C_2,}\;c_1,c_2,c_3,\;\mathcal{C_1,C_2}$

The *order* of transportation doesn't matter, but two *identical* labeled groups $\mathcal C_1, C_2$ occur twice in the sequence. so we are double counting for each coach (e.g. $W,X,Y,Z$ could be in the first or second $\mathcal C_1$),
so we need to divide the initial expression by $2!2! =4$,
giving the book answer of
$\Large\frac{25!}{(4!)^4(3!)^34}$

Comment: I got my mistake thanks

Comment: You are welcome ! $\;\;$